# eval() is returning a null value

Tags: javascript, eval, calculator

I am trying to code a calculator but the equal button is not working with eval() and its giving null with (Invalid or unexpected token
    at HTMLButtonElement.)

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
const screen = document.querySelector('.screen');
const equalbtn = document.querySelector('.btnequal');

for(i=0; i<btns.length; i++){

    btns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var number = this.getAttribute("data-num");
        screen.value += number;
        //console.log(screen.value);
    })
}

equalbtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(screen.value === ''){
       alert('Please select a value');

    } else {

    let value = eval(screen.value);
    console.log(value);

    screen.value = value;
    }
})
```

Comment: please post html also

Comment: the code works fine.  post a full working snippet that replicates the problem.  null is most likely due to not having `data-num=` declared in your .btn button

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a running calculator based on your given code. Note that I never got any null value. Maybe your html code was wrong, you didn't add any.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
const screen = document.querySelector('.screen');
const equalbtn = document.querySelector('.btnequal');

let reset = false;

for(let i=0; i<btns.length; i++){

    btns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        let number = this.getAttribute("data-num");
        if(reset){
          screen.value = number;
          reset = false;
        }
        else{
          screen.value += number;
        }
    })
}

equalbtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(screen.value === ''){
       alert('Please select a value');
    } else {
      let value = eval(screen.value);
      screen.value = value;
      reset = true;
    }
})
```

```html
<input class="screen" readonly="readonly" />
<button class="btn" data-num="1">1</button>
<button class="btn" data-num="2">2</button>
<button class="btn" data-num="3">3</button>
<button class="btn" data-num="+">+</button>
<button class="btn" data-num="-">-</button>
<button class="btn" data-num="*">*</button>
<button class="btn" data-num="/">/</button>
<button class="btnequal">=</button>
```

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btnequal">=</button> 

I just changes my class to 

<button type="button" class="btnequal">=</button> now its working fine. 

I used "btn btnname" structure throughout the html code i.e for all button including CLEAR but its only effects  "=" button why ? what is difference between "btn btnequal" and "btnequal"

Comment: @ErfanAnjum That makes sense. Using `btn btnequal` will bind the first handler (for the numbers) to the equal button (plus the second handler with `eval`). The former handler searches for the `data-num` attribute which the `btnequal` doesn't have. This then leads to your `null` exception. You found and fixed your own error now :) — PS: If you think this is the correct answer consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it by clicking the tick on the top left of the answer. This way the question is marked as solved and not shown to other people again :)